# get the size of UIImageView programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, uiimageview

i'm creating an app for iPhone and iPad. and now i would want to retrieve the size of an UIImageView on different phone screen. I have tried with following code:

```
print("width \(BubbleBackground.frame.size.width)")
print("height \(BubbleBackground.frame.size.height)")
print("width1 \(BubbleBackground.bounds.size.width)")
print("height1 \(BubbleBackground.bounds.size.height)")
print("width2\(BubbleBackground.image!.size.width)")
print("height2\(BubbleBackground.image!.size.height)")
```

I have tried with the code above, but yet they return me a constant value no matter it is running in iPhone 5, iPhone 6, iPhone 6 plus or iPad. Does anyone have an idea how can i get the image size when it is running on different device?

Comment: may be you have set the fixed height in your attribute

Comment: where do you put this code? if in `viewDidLoad` it might not be correct since layout haven't started yet

Comment: Nop, it is aspect ratio, the image is resize to bigger resolution on iPad and small resolution on iPhone

Comment: Check whether you have set the size constraints, and also if you have set the set to fit size content.

Comment: @Tj3n Yea you are amazing! you are right i should not put them in viewDidLoad!! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have some constraints to change the imageView frame according to the screen size. Then you can use `.layoutIfNeeded()` on the `UIImageView` (BubbleBackground.layoutIfNeeded()) to get its runtime size.

make sure you do this in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews` or anytime after these events.

Comment: Yea i have figured out that i should not put them in viewDidLoad()

Answer (score 1):

Your image will be the same size on all devices unless you have set constraints on the image that cause it to resize to fit the current screen size.

Constraints are most often added using Xcode's Interface Builder but can also be added programatically.

**Adding constraints using the Interface Builder**
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraintsinInterfaceBuidler.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH10-SW1

**Adding Constraints Programatically** https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html